# Show blank text boxes and buttons in MS Access form even when there is no data

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a split form in MS Access that is bound to a query.  Sometimes this query will return no results and when this happens, the form goes totally blank.

Is there a way to have the form still show all the fields and buttons and just have the fields be blank?

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer [here](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-20.html).

I'm guessing you can't get around condition A as it sounds like it's set up to have filter (that sometimes returns no results), but check whether you have any of scenarios described in condition B and try to fix those.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Count the records at the OnOpen event of the form and Cancel the event it the count is zero and pop a message that nothing is to be shown.

Comment: I would use this method except that it is going to be a live reporting tool between production and supply chain.  I want the form to show blank so that when a new entry is logged, it shows up on the form.  If the form closes when the query is empty, supply chain will have to keep opening the form to check.

Comment: Then change the logging function - if the form is closed - to open the form when that new entry is logged.

Comment: How do I change that?

Comment: I don't know. You haven't revealed any of your code at all.

Comment: In thinking about that, would that actually work?  This tool is going to be used on multiple computers, so I don't think changing the logging function will be able to open the form on all the computers that have this tool open.

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps not. It is not possible to advice without any detail or description of what you are doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74754/discussion-between-mackles24-and-gustav).